# Failure [INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]

Tags: android-studio, redmi-permission

i am using redmi note 3.. if you know, while running an android studio app for testing over the USB, you get a popup in which you have to allow the permission to install the app over USB...It was working fine until, **by mistake, i marked "Remember my choice" and "denied"**. i tried a lot but can't find any way to re-enable that popup... There should must be a way to re-enable this setting...If anybody can help?? Thank you.
(Also i did pretty much research on internet but can't find anyway, also noone has faced this problem before(may be). Is there any way other than factory reset?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, there is no way to fix it.. I had to Delete that project and start new one and copy pasted all the files in that one and it's working fine now..Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 **Pro**, and using Xamarin (quite similar to Android Studio) to test mobile apps I had the same error *Failure[INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER]*

> You have to:
>
> 1.- Go **Settings** on your device.
>
> 2.- Go **Permissions**.
>
> 3.- Go **Install via USB**.

Your test application should be here. Delete it from the list (if several apps) and the problem may be solved.

I hope to be useful ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but still the same error..i had tried that too and also tried again but no luck.. :(

Comment: maybe in the "Permissions" tag you could select other option, not the Install via USB one, and may be find something to enable the test app again.

Comment: Fixed it... Thank you

Comment: Post the solution Tan_007 ;)